# Newly installed AMD system won't recognize old Intel RAID 0

Tags: ssd, raid, amd-ryzen

My old RAID 0 setup isn't being recognized in RAIDXpert2, and I can't seem to figure out how to make it again, without losing data. Here's my timeline:

1. Intel i7 2600k + Z77 board
2. Intel i7 6700k + Z170 board
3. Intel i7 6700k + Z270 board
4. Ryzen 3900X + B450 Tomahawk board

I created the array back on my Z77 board, then simply recreated it on my Z170 board and Z270 board. However, once moving to my new AMD build, my two SSDs in RAID 0 show up as two individual arrays. Basically:

- Array 1: Samsung SSD 250GB
- Array 2: Samsung SSD 250GB

What I want is:

- Array 1: Samsung SSD 250GB + Samsung SSD 250GB (RAID 0)

Is there a way in RAIDXpert2 that allows me to recreate 1 array with both drives in RAID 0, instead of having the two arrays it has now, without losing any data?

Comment: To avoid this problem in the future, I strongly suggest you use software RAID. (You’re already using software RAID anyway, so-called FakeRAID.)

Comment: @DanielB Honestly I'm going to take backup of this current setup and move to single SSDs instead. Do you think disabling everything that has to do with RAID in the BIOS would work, then doing a software RAID with the two drives in Windows? I haven't worked with software RAID before, so I don't even know where to begin